# Cosa significa "perdere la cintura" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Se colpite secco e giusto a quel dato punto della mascella, anche Joe Louis piegherà le ginocchia, il suo organismo non reagirà più, avrà inizio la sua agonia di campione che durerà dieci secondi. L’agonia mortale è più lunga di quella di un boxeur che **perde la cintura**, ed è straziante, crudele, indicibile...

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "perdere la cintura" in questo contesto? Una ricerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere che è un'espressione che si usa nel pugilato, ma non ho trovato il significato.

Comment: Per tutti quelli che hanno risposto citando gli usi contemporanei nel pugilato: considerando per esempio che la WBA è nata quindici anni dopo la pubblicazione di _Cronaca familiare_, potreste verificare se le cinture di campione in carica come le vediamo oggi fossero in uso già negli anni Quaranta? Non dico di no: è solo che vorrei capire da quando si usano.

Comment: World Boxing Association (WBA), fondata nel 1921 come National Boxing Association (NBA), poi così ridenominata dal 1962;
World Boxing Council (WBC), fondata nel 1963;
International Boxing Federation (IBF), fondata nel 1983;
World Boxing Organization (WBO), fondata nel 1988;
International Boxing Organization (IBO), fondata nel 1988

Comment: La [WBA](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Boxing_Association) è nata nel 1921 come NBA e ha cambiato nome nel 1962.

Comment: Esatto, @abarisone, mi confermi che la WBA esiste dal 1962, 15 anni dopo la pubblicazione del romanzo di Pratolini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cintura è il trofeo per eccellenza nella boxe. Perdere la cintura significa perdere il titolo di campione in una delle varie categorie del pugilato.

> - Tenere in mano quella [cintura](http://www.laprovinciadivarese.it/stories/Sport/papa-avevi-ragione-ho-vinto-la-cintura_1185519_11/). Tenere in mano la cintura di campione italiano, non è facile. No: perché è oro. Preziosa e pesante allo stesso tempo. E, quando Michele Esposito, ieri, è venuto in redazione a farcela vedere, non abbiamo resistito alla tentazione di tenerla tra le nostre mani.

(www.laprovinciadivarese.it)

[image]

In merito alla curiosità espressa riguardo al fatto se negli anni ‘40 si usava la cintura trofeo nel pugilato:

Da [La storia del pugilato](http://www.panathlonarea1.it/home/panathlonplanet/regolesport/13-03-19/LA_STORIA_DEL_PUGILATO.aspx):

> - Il primo italiano ad indossare la cintura di campione del mondo fu il friulano Primo Carnera che, nel 1933 sul ring di Long Island, batté lo statunitense Sherkey Jack per KO alla sesta ripresa.

[image]

L’uso della cintura trofeo nel puglilato risale agli inizi del ‘800.

[Championship belt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Championship_belt):

> The first belt given as a prize for accomplishments within the ring was presented in 1810 by King George III to bare-knuckle boxer Tom Cribb, after he defeated Tom Molineaux, an American former slave.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Perfetto, grazie per l'aggiunta delle attestazioni d'epoca sull'uso delle cinture.

Answer (score 2):

Il boxeur che perde la cintura è il pugile campione in carica che viene sconfitto e di conseguenza perde il titolo, rappresentato dalla cintura.

Senza entrare troppo nello specifico all'interno della WBA - World Boxing Association i pugili vengono suddivisi in categorie diverse in base al peso.
Per ogni categoria c'è il titolo con la corrispondente cintura.

Il pugile [Joe Louis](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Louis) riportato nel passaggio da te riportato era un peso massimo.

Answer (score 2):

Il campione di pugilato ha come riconoscenza "la cintura"; se la perde, vuol dire che non è più lui il campione, ed in questo contesto vengono descritte le sue reazioni con aggettivi come "straziante, crudele, indicibile..."

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!